# How to cast varchar to xml when there is special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some `varchar` data with special html characters like

```
&ecirc;    &iacute;    &uacute;    &eacute;
```

For example:

```
select convert(xml, '<p>g&ecirc;nero h&iacute; conte&uacute;do, &eacute;</p>')
```

Running this causes an error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 11, well formed check: undeclared entity

How can I convert it to XML without having to replace one by one?

Comment: Replace the ampersands in the string with an entity reference: `CONVERT(xml, REPLACE('<p>g&ecirc;nero h&iacute; conte&uacute;do, &eacute;</p>','&', '&amp;'))`